# Fine Uploader PHP Endpoint - Specify Upload folder?

Tags: php, fine-uploader

I am using Fine Uploader (https://fineuploader.com/) with a traditional server.

I am using the PHP example provided (https://github.com/FineUploader/php-traditional-server) and all works fine, files get uploaded fine.

What I am trying to do is somehow modify it so I can specify my own upload folder. Ideally, I would specify the folder path on the upload page and pass it to the endpoint.

What is the easiest way to do that?

Comment: code snippet please

Comment: The codes is at [https://github.com/FineUploader/php-traditional-server](https://github.com/FineUploader/php-traditional-server) , I was just wondering if someone had the same problem and how they solved it.

Comment: The file I need to modify is handler.php: [https://github.com/FineUploader/php-traditional-server/blob/master/handler.php]https://github.com/FineUploader/php-traditional-server/blob/master/handler.php - by default the handler creates an unique folder in 'files' folder and then uploads the file there. What I would like to do is specify the folder myself and then upload it there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change
`$result = $uploader->combineChunks("files"); // Line 76` and 
`$result = $uploader->handleUpload("files"); // Line 81`
in endpoint.php with 
`$result = $uploader->combineChunks("whereyouwanttoupload");` and `$result = $uploader->handleUpload("whereyouwanttoupload");`

Comment: And how do you override the uuid folder to a custom name folder?